# How can I calculate $P(2-X<Y<X)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $X,Y$ are independent $N(1,1)$.

How can I calculate $P(2-X<Y<X)$?

Comment: Draw a sketch of the $x$-$y$ plane and mark on it the region where the point $(x,y)$ satisfies $2-x < y < x$.

Answer (score 3):

It will help to draw pictures of the regions involved as you go through this.

[Indeed, you could even start by drawing up an $X,Y$ plane with the bivariate mean and some contours drawn in (e.g. at radius 1 and 2). Draw on the region in the $X,Y$ plane that you want the probability for; this should already show you how to proceed. Or you can skip that and move straight to the next step.]

Consider $X_1=X-1$ and $Y_1=Y-1$. Write the inequalities in terms of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ and look at what region that defines in a diagram of the $X_1,Y_1$ plane.

You may be able to answer by inspection of the relevant region in the $X_1,Y_1$ plane (it's quite plain what the answer is, and that answer can be formalized by a simple appeal to symmetry).

Failing that, if you can see (or show) that  $U=X_1-Y_1$ and $V=X_1+Y_1$ are also bivariate normal and uncorrelated (even simply on the basis that $kU,kV$ for a particular choice of $k$ is a rotation about the origin of a circular symmetric bivariate distribution, for example), then consider the effect on the inequalities to reparameterizing to $U,V$ (that is, write the inequalities in terms of $U$ and $V$).

If you look at the resulting region in the ($U,V$) plane you should be able to see how to write a somewhat more formal argument that establishes the answer quite easily.

Answer (score 3):

So if you had two real values $a,b$ you would compute the probability $P(a<Y<b)$ as $$P(a<Y<b)=\int_a^b f_Y(y)dy,$$ right? ($f_Y(y)$ is the density of $Y$).

Now, since the boundaries are also random, you have to make this calculation *integrating for every possible value of the boundaries*, i.e.,

$$P(2-X<Y<X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{2-x}^x f_Y(y)dy\right)f_X(x)dx.$$

Comment: This is a brute-force approach to the problem that makes it appear to be much harder than it actually is.

Comment: I know, I know, that is why I upvoted the other answer, which is much neater.

Comment: I actually like this answer.